# Booting with text only on 1920*1200

Tags: 11.04, ati, plymouth

I have the proprietary ATI driver, which breaks plymouth. I would rather see the whole console output on the full resolution of my screen while booting.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing "quiet splash" options from kernel command line, obtained modifying `/etc/default/grub` and executing `sudo update-grub`, should make you see booting messages.

The console switches to hires mode after start of upstart job `console-setup`.